# Live Preview (preview-kit) is not updating in real-time

Tags: next.js, sanity

I recently updated my Sanity Studio to the latest version (currently at `3.16.7`) and with that I also had to migrate to the new `@sanity/preview-kit` for Live Preview support.

I followed all the guides and examples I could find but can't get the real-time preview to work (that is where the previewed page is updated in real-time as you are typing new content in Sanity Studio). This used to work with the previous Preview implementation from the older version.

Just to be clear: Loading the page in preview mode works (it shows the draft content) and changes are reflected when I reload the previewed page, but it is not reloaded in real-time (as you type).

The attached screenshot shows an overview of the code involved:

- `getStaticProps` checks for `draftMode` and if that is enabled, the `fetch()` used to get all the page data from Sanity uses the `previewDrafts` perspective and has `useCdn` disabled.
- In the main `<Layout />` component, I have a `PreviewProvider` component that is dynamically loaded.
- The `PreviewProvider` loads a `LiveQueryProvider` component with:

  - `client` set to a Sanity client with the `previewDrafts` perspective
  - `token` is set to a valid read token
  - `logger` set to console

The browser console shows the following log when loading the page in preview mode while editing:

```
[@sanity/preview-kit]: fetch documents count
[@sanity/preview-kit]: documents count 894
[@sanity/preview-kit]: With the current configuration you can expect that: Updates are applied in real-time. The cache is set to max 3000 documents.
```

Screenshot of the code:
[image]

Comment: I am facing the same issue but with slight twist. Using latest sanity and nextjs version, preview data shows up on screen and instantly it flashes and screen goes blank. No errors in console or terminal.

Comment: In Next apps, you should use `import { useLiveQuery } from 'next-sanity/preview';` instead. This solved the issue for me. It seems strange as it's just re-exporting it, so couldn't tell you why, but I had the same issue and this was the fix

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Jamie. Unfortunately, it did not make any difference for me.

Comment: Sorry about that. If you're able to put a small reproduction together I'd be happy to take a look and help solve